# Running "npm run dev" on pet-shop-project fails and gives errors

Tags: solidity

Hi whenever I try to run the `npm run dev` in the terminal on [pet-shop-project](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) tutorial, it comes up with a long list of error here below the error.
hope to solve the issue by your help.

Thanks in advance.

```
PS C:\pet-shop-tutorial> npm run dev

> pet-shop@1.0.0 dev C:\pet-shop-tutorial
> lite-server

npm : C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\lib\lite-server.js:33
At line:1 char:1
+ npm run dev
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\Ali\Ap...te-server.js:33:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

      throw (err);
      ^
SyntaxError: C:\pet-shop-tutorial\bs-config.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 70
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:671:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at start (C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\lib\lite-server.js:28:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\bin\lite-server:7:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
npm

ERR!

code
 ELIFECYCLE
npm

ERR!

errno
 1
npm

ERR!
 pet-shop@1.0.0 dev: `lite-server`
npm

ERR!
 Exit status 1
npm

ERR!

npm

ERR!
 Failed at the pet-shop@1.0.0 dev script.
npm

ERR!
 This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm

ERR!
 A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm

ERR!


     C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-30T01_41_54_260Z-debug.log
```

bs-config-json contents

```
 {
  "server": {
    "baseDir": ["./src", "./build/contracts"],

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `bs-config.json`? It contains a syntax error.

Comment: Hi for sure    {
  "server": {
    "baseDir": ["./src", "./build/contracts"],

  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `bs-config.json` isn't valid JSON. You have an extra comma after the array. It should look like this:

```
{ "server": { "baseDir": ["./src", "./build/contracts"] } }
```

That's why you get this error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\pet-shop-tutorial\bs-config.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 70
```

You can validate your JSON using a JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com/.